# online wysiwyg editor drag to change table row/column height

Tags: html, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor

I am trying to pick a WYSIWYG editor for my website, which can drag the table row or column's border to change the width/height, just like some desktop word processors do. I tried lots of awesome editors like CKEditor, TinyMCE, but none of them has this function. BTW it's a PHP site so ASP-based editors won't work. Can someone give an advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CKEditor provides a plugin to resize columns: http://nightly.ckeditor.com/latest/ckeditor/_samples/tableresize.html but the height is adjusted automatically according to the contents of the cells.

Comment: It seems that they have removed that sample from the list. You can download the editor and test it on your server. Just remember to add that plugin before clicking the Download button: http://ckeditor.com/addon/tableresize